# Jasmine Unit Testing: Error: Cannot find module 'parser.js'

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

I am new to unit testing and I just installed jasmine and wrote this test program.

```
   var grabNums = require('parser')

describe("parsenpmr test", function(){
    it(" .3grabs possible phone and conference numbers", function(){
        expect(grabNums.grabNums("the phone number is (914)-817-3535 and the conference code is 5852753333 please call in at 6:00AM").toBe(['(914)8173535','5852753333']))
    })
})
```

[My Directory organization looks like this at the moment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LiXg.png)

and this is the error I am getting

```
> outlookparser2@1.0.0 test C:\Users\kaizert\eclipse-workspaceREAL\client_S4B\src\outlookParser2
> jasmine

module.js:549
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'parser.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\kaizert\eclipse-workspaceREAL\client_S4B\src\outlookParser2\spec\parserspec.js:1:78)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

What do I need to change? Again I am new to unit testing so I apologize if there is an easy solution to this, I could not find anything online.

Comment: Did you install the module you are using `parser` ?

Comment: Parser is the .js file I made that contains the functions I would like to test. Each function in it has a corresponding `module.exports.functionName` statement

Comment: Could you share its code and the folder structure?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the fix would be:
var parser = require('./parser');

Answer (score -4):

I figured out my problem. I don't suspect it will be an issue for many other people but I was improperly referencing my actual .js file. I had

```
var parser = require('parser');
```

when I should have had

```
var parser = require('parser');
```

Comment: whats the difference between two?